# How to fix the org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl@779de014 is closed issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, connection

I am trying to create or update user with Hibernate 5 and it throws following exception:
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl@779de014 is closed

I'm using the following technologies:

- Spring 4
- Hibernate 5
- Maven
- Eclipse

This is my `UserDaoImpl.Java`:

```
package com.fasttrack.users.dao;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.fasttrack.users.model.User;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDaoImpl extends AbstractDao implements UserDao
{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public boolean saveUser(User user)
    {
         Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
          try
          {
             session.persist(user);
             return true;
          }

          catch (Exception e) 
          {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

          finally 
          {
              session.close(); 
           }

    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<User> getUsers()
    {
         List<User> users;
         Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
          try
          {
              users=(List<User>) session.createQuery("FROM USER"); 
              return users;
          }

          catch (Exception e) 
          {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

          finally {
              session.close(); 
           }
        return null;
    }

    public User getUser(String id)
    {
         User user;
         Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
          try
          {
              user=(User)session.get(User.class,id); 
              return user;
          }

          catch (Exception e) 
          {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

          finally 
          {
              session.close(); 
           }

    }



    public boolean updateUser(User user)
    {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        try
            {
                session.saveOrUpdate(user);
                return true;
            }

        catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

        finally
            {
                session.close();
            }
    }


    public boolean deleteUserById(String id)
    {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(id);

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        try
            {
                session.delete(user);
                return true;
            }

        catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

        finally
            {
                session.close();
            }
    }

}
```

This is my `TestUserDao.java`:

```
import com.fasttrack.users.dao.UserDao;
import com.fasttrack.users.model.User;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/Hibernate-test.xml")

public class TestUserDao
{
    @Autowired(required=true)
    public UserDao userDao;

    @Test
    public void testSaveUser()
    {
        User user=new User();
        user.setFirstName("TestUser1");
        boolean result=userDao.saveUser(user);
    }
}
```

Error Message:

```
Mar 01, 2017 1:14:52 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper getDefaultTestExecutionListenerClassNames
INFO: Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
Mar 01, 2017 1:14:52 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper getTestExecutionListeners
INFO: Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@6be46e8f, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@3567135c, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@327471b5, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@4157f54e, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@90f6bfd, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@47f6473]
Mar 01, 2017 1:14:52 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Hibernate-test.xml]
Mar 01, 2017 1:14:53 PM org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@2a5ca609: startup date [Wed Mar 01 13:14:53 EST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Mar 01, 2017 1:14:53 PM org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from class path resource [database.properties]
Mar 01, 2017 1:14:53 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor <init>
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
Mar 01, 2017 1:14:53 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.6.Final}
Mar 01, 2017 1:14:53 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Mar 01, 2017 1:14:53 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Mar 01, 2017 1:14:54 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Mar 01, 2017 1:14:54 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
Mar 01, 2017 1:14:54 PM org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@130d63be] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
Generated Id: USER0
Mar 01, 2017 1:14:55 PM org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager doRollbackOnCommitException
SEVERE: Commit exception overridden by rollback exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl@6b410923 is closed
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.errorIfClosed(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.commit(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:582)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.saveUser(Unknown Source)
    at TestUserDao.testSaveUser(TestUserDao.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Hibernate xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">


    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />
      <context:component-scan  base-package="com.timelee.*" />


    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>


     <!--  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  -->

     <bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
       <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>

    </bean>



    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.timelee.timesheet.model</value>
                <value>com.timelee.users.model</value>
                <value>com.timelee.*</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql:false}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql:false}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>       
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: Please share the `Hibernate-test.xml` contents.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found something strange in your error message "**SEVERE**: **Commit exception overridden by rollback exception**". If you look at the try block in `UserDaoImpl.Java` file you have return statement, which closes the hibernate connection before returning. And you have `session.close()` statement in finally block which doesn't make sense, since the connection was already closed. Would you mind removing `session.close()` statement and try again. Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: closing the session before returning Object also leads the same failure to me, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the [Spring Framework User Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight), in a `@Transactional` block, you don't need to manually manage the Hibernate `Session` since the `TransactionInterceptor` does that for you.

So, instead of:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<User> getUsers() {
    List<User> users;
    Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    try
    {
        users=(List<User>) session.createQuery("FROM USER"); 
        return users;
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
      session.close(); 
    }
    return null;
}
```

you should do this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<User> getUsers() {
    try {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createQuery("FROM USER")
        .getResultList(); 
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Aside from removing the `session.close` call, there were more issues that I fixed in your example:

1. You were not calling `getResultList()` on the Hibernate `Query` which, instead, you cast to  `List<User>`
2. Calling `e..printStackTrace();` is bad. You should use a Logger framework instead. In this case, it's better to propagate the exception further instead of hiding it under the carpet.
3. Why would you return `null` when you expect a `List`? If there is no result, and empty `List` is a much better alternative. In your example, when you got an exception, you'd return `null` which it's indistinguishable from the case when you'd get an empty result set.

Comment: getCurrentSession() may not work everywhere; Since session object is not thread safe. So what about openSession() per request in a multi threaded environment?

Comment: Use Spring transaction and Session handling instead of doing it manually via openSession.

Comment: Would you please guide me through using it?

Comment: The Spring documentation is the right resource to guide you.

Comment: What about using this in the Hibernate conf: <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>  ?????

Comment: Don't use that! Check out the Spring and Hibernate documentation for more details.

Comment: I found no suggestion of not using it in Hibernate doc!     http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html

Comment: Try the Spring documentation as well.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled over a quite similar stack trace when updating a legacy application to Hibernate 5 / Spring 4 and implementing transaction support while I was at it.

We are using two database connections (two SessionFactories and two TransactionManagers).

The problem was that I nested a transaction on connection B inside a transaction on connection A. Like this:

```
apiCall
  -> @Transactional 
     doSomethingWithConnectionA
     -> @Transactional
        doSomethingWithConnectionB
```

The issue was gone, when I excuted the functions one after the other from the same level

```
apiCall
  -> @Transactional 
     doSomethingWithConnectionA
  -> @Transactional
     doSomethingWithConnectionB
```

Comment: I do not have redundant Transactional in my code as shown above