# org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl@59edd0e6 is closed

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, servlets

Hi Im getting the issue org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl@59edd0e6 is closed while creating the crud example with jsp-servlet-hibernate-mysql-example.

whenever Im hitting the link to browser http://localhost:8080/jsp-servlet-hibernate-mysql-example/new the add user form comes and when Im adding the details and trying to save nothing is happening and a blank page is showing with a link http://localhost:8080/jsp-servlet-hibernate-mysql-example/insert.

In my console, this issue arise org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl@59edd0e6

Please help someone to resolve this issue.

Im attaching all necessary files please have a look and let me know if I can give you more input from my side.

```
Mar 22, 2020 8:38:09 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.7.Final}
Mar 22, 2020 8:38:09 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Hibernate Java Config serviceRegistry created
Mar 22, 2020 8:38:10 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
Mar 22, 2020 8:38:10 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Mar 22, 2020 8:38:10 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql_database?user=root]
Mar 22, 2020 8:38:10 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Mar 22, 2020 8:38:10 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Mar 22, 2020 8:38:10 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Mar 22, 2020 8:38:11 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
Mar 22, 2020 8:38:11 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl applyImportSources
INFO: HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@71cd6849'
Mar 22, 2020 8:38:11 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl@3551bb9a is closed
org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl@aaa541f is closed

public class UserDao {

    // save the user
    public void saveUser(User user) {

        Transaction transaction = null;

        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {

            // start a transaction
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            // save the user object
            session.save(user);

            // commit transaction
            transaction.commit();


        } catch (Exception e) {

            if (transaction != null) {

                transaction.rollback();
            }
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}


public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionfactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

        if (sessionfactory == null) {

            try {

                Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

                // Hibernate settings equivalent to hibernate.cfg.xml's properties

                Properties setting = new Properties();
                setting.put(Environment.DRIVER, "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                setting.put(Environment.URL, "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql_database?user=root");
                setting.put(Environment.USER, "root");
                setting.put(Environment.PASS, "Shivank@220");
                setting.put(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");

                setting.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, "False");
                setting.put(Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS, "thread");
                setting.put(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "create-drop");

                configuration.setProperties(setting);
                configuration.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);

                ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                        .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

                System.out.println("Hibernate Java Config serviceRegistry created");
                sessionfactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

                return sessionfactory;


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return sessionfactory;

    }
}


package usermanagement.webserv;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import usermanagement.dao.UserDao;
import usermanagement.model.User;

@WebServlet("/")
public class UserServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private UserDao userDao;

    public void init() {

        userDao = new UserDao();
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        doGet(request, response);
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String action = request.getServletPath();

        try {
            switch (action) {

            case "/new":
                showNewForm(request, response);
                break;
            case "/insert":
                insertUser(request, response);
                break;
            case "/delete":
                deleteUser(request, response);
                break;
            case "/edit":
                showEditForm(request, response);
                break;
            case "/update":
                updateUser(request, response);
                break;
            default:
                listUser(request, response);
                break;
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void insertUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String country = request.getParameter("country");

        User newUser = new User(name, email, country);
        userDao.saveUser(newUser);
        response.sendRedirect("list");

    }

    private void listUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        List<User> listUser = userDao.getAllUser();
        request.setAttribute("listUser", listUser);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("user-list.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    private void updateUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String country = request.getParameter("country");

        User user = new User(id, name, email, country);
        userDao.updateUser(user);
        response.sendRedirect("list");
    }

    private void showEditForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        User existingUser = userDao.getUser(id);

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("user-form.jsp");
        request.setAttribute("user", existingUser);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

    }

    private void deleteUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        userDao.deleteUser(id);
        response.sendRedirect("list");
    }

    private void showNewForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("user-form.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Thanks in Advance.

```
[error console][1]
[hibernateUtil][2]
[Servlet][3]
[servlet_continue][4]
[userDao][5]


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYxIe.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKBWb.jpg
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5Jcm.jpg
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/itM5U.jpg
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNvDD.jpg
```

Comment: Post your code and also check where you're closing the session.

Comment: i have attached the screenshot please refer as im not able to post entire code

Comment: Can't see your screenshot. Also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538817/org-hibernate-resource-jdbc-internal-logicalconnectionmanagedimpl779de014-is-cl/44365833#44365833

Comment: I have added all the code please see and let me know. - issue is im not able to save the user details while taking input from user.

Comment: you should also close the session (session.close()) as you are using getSessionFactory().openSession(). If you want to manage it automatically than you could use getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession() which is alive upto the life-cycle of your transaction (when you do transaction.commit() or transaction.rollback())

Comment: Instead of using getSessionFactory().openSession(), now im using getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession() but seems the same issue no changes. same error i'm getting.

Comment: @Shubham can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, but the impoted file for bean User is incorrect by mistake that's why this issue raised.