# How to set JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit NOT to 'default'

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, weblogic, spring-data-jpa, weblogic12c

Normally all the default configurations of `Spring-boot` are totally fine. But now I need to deploy my application to a Weblogic 12.2 Server and I am facing some issues regarding persistence.

I just wondering how to set the JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit NOT to 'default'. Because by startup of the application I can see those logs:

```
2017-05-23 08:16:34.608  INFO 30827 - j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean []: Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-05-23 08:16:35.090  INFO 30827 - o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  []: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-05-23 08:16:36.025  INFO 30827 - org.hibernate.Version                    []: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.11.Final}
2017-05-23 08:16:36.026  INFO 30827 - org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            []: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-05-23 08:16:36.029  INFO 30827 - org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            []: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-05-23 08:16:36.925  INFO 30827 - o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   []: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-05-23 08:16:39.632  INFO 30827 - org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            []: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
2017-05-23 08:16:48.205  INFO 30827 - j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean []: Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-05-23 08:16:55.348  INFO 30827 - o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  []: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

So I am not sure if weblogic is using the default persistence unit (eclipselink) or really hibernate. So I was thinking to set the persistence unit explicity anywhere in my `spring-boot` application.

Is there any way to set hibernate as default unit explicit?

**EDIT:**

I was asking this before because I get an exception by runtime. The `org.eclipse.persistence` libraries are used for unmarshalling xml.

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException: 
Exception Description: No conversion value provided for the value [ToConfirm] in field [@SubStatus].
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[subStatus-->@SubStatus]
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(at.myCompany.bookingHubClient.schema.BookingHubUserTypes.BookResponse --> [DatabaseTable(BookResponse)])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException.noFieldValueConversionToAttributeValueProvided(DescriptorException.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.converters.ObjectTypeConverter.convertDataValueToObjectValue(ObjectTypeConverter.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBEnumTypeConverter.convertDataValueToObjectValue(JAXBEnumTypeConverter.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping.convertDataValueToObjectValue(XMLDirectMapping.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping.getAttributeValue(XMLDirectMapping.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping.getAttributeValue(XMLDirectMapping.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLDirectMappingNodeValue.attribute(XMLDirectMappingNodeValue.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.UnmarshalRecordImpl.startElement(UnmarshalRecordImpl.java:922)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshallerHandler.startElement(SAXUnmarshallerHandler.java:373)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:380)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:614)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3135)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:880)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:118)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at weblogic.xml.jaxp.WebLogicXMLReader.parse(WebLogicXMLReader.java:133)
    at weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLReader.parse(RegistryXMLReader.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.XMLReader.parse(XMLReader.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLUnmarshaller.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:323)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.XmlRootElementJaxbProvider.readFrom(XmlRootElementJaxbProvider.java:140)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.AbstractRootElementJaxbProvider.readFrom(AbstractRootElementJaxbProvider.java:134)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1085)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:852)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:786)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse$1.call(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:419)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse.runInScopeIfPossible(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse.readEntity(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:112)
    at at.myCompany.bookingHubClient.client.RestClient.doWSCallBook(RestClient.java:85)
    at at.myCompany.thirdPartyBookingService.service.impl.hotel.BookResponseServiceImpl.getBookResponse(BookResponseServiceImpl.java:36)
    ... 78 common frames omitted
```

Sure I see there is a conversion issue, but on tomcat its running and I dont use any `eclipse` libraries. So means any library of weblogic is overriding mine.

The exception occours at this line:

```
 javax.ws.rs.core.Response bookResponse = response.readEntity(BookResponse.class);
```

Any idea to get the app running again?

This is my weblogic.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:context-root>/third-party-booking-service</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>com.google.common.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>javax.annotation.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>com.sun.jersey.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.jboss.logging.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>antlr.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Comment: As you can see from your logging it uses hibernate. Also it is just a name of the unit to use (which you would generally specify in the `persistence.xml` it has nothing to do with which provided is used).

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for the comment. I asked it before beause some of eclipse.persistence libraries are used. I edited my question. Maybe you have an idea.

Comment: But that is something completely different (and you won't fix that by specifying a different unit name). You are using JAX-RS and you are probably not shipping that with your application. Hence your app is going to use the JAX-RS libs from your container which cannot see your hibernate classes (different class loaders) and hence using the default eclipse classes. I suggest to explicitly configure jax-rs and you probably want to switch class loading the parent-last (or whatever that is named in WebLogic).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it when you configure, but you need to configure your datasource, transactionManager and Entitymanager yourself. Something like this will do

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "notDefaultEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "notDefaultTransactionManager",
    basePackageClasses = notDefaultRepository.class)
public class SomesqlDb{

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSourcenotDefault() {
        return getDataSource(poolSize, driverClassName, jdbcUrl, userName, password);
    }

    @Bean(name = "notDefaultTransactionManager")
    PlatformTransactionManager notDefaultTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory notDefaultEntityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(notDefaultEntityManagerFactory);
        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean(name = "notDefaultEntityManagerFactory")
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean notDefaultEntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSourcenotDefault());
        em.setPackagesToScan(notDefaultRepository.class.getPackage().getName(), notDefaultBi.class.getPackage().getName());
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("notDefaultDb");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        return em;
    }
}
```

In this case persistance unit is named as notDefaultDb. This is done by this line `em.setPersistenceUnitName("notDefaultDb")`

**EDIT :** Based on inputs from @M.Denium, this can be done even simpler if you name your entity manager factory as `entityManagerFactory`(default) . So that all the Auto configuration works out of the box and you would end up configuring only entity manager factory.

```
    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSourcenotDefault());
        em.setPackagesToScan(notDefaultRepository.class.getPackage().getName(), notDefaultBi.class.getPackage().getName());
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("notDefaultDb");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        return em;
    }
```

Comment: No you don't... You would only need to configure the `EntityManagerFactory` and just leave the name `entityManagerFactory` to prevent manual configuration of all the other related stuff.

Comment: @M.Deinum you are right. I will update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps someone, the following works for me on WebSphere ND 8.5.5.15/16. The Spring boot version i am using is 2.1.8.RELEASE, and it works through subsequent upgrades up to the latest 2.3.4.

```
@Configuration
public class JPAConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());

        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.example.model" });
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        return em;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
       
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx:db");
        dataSource.setUsername("username");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");

        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

If you want more information about LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean, the documentation is [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html). The important part is:

> FactoryBean that creates a JPA EntityManagerFactory according to JPA's
> standard container bootstrap contract. This is the most powerful way
> to set up a shared JPA EntityManagerFactory in a Spring application
> context; the EntityManagerFactory can then be passed to JPA-based DAOs
> via dependency injection. Note that switching to a JNDI lookup or to a
> LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean definition is just a matter of
> configuration!
>
> As with LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean, configuration settings are
> usually read in from a META-INF/persistence.xml config file, residing
> in the class path, according to the general JPA configuration
> contract. However, this FactoryBean is more flexible in that you can
> override the location of the persistence.xml file, specify the JDBC
> DataSources to link to, etc.